# Redux Sagas - dispatch undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I'm new to redux-sagas and am still trying to get my head round how they work. I'm trying to bind a redux-saga function to one of my components which makes an API request then dispatch an action with the data from the response. I'm getting an error of dispatch is undefined when trying to pass dispatch to my saga functions arguments as per their documentation. Here is my setup:

**Thumbnails Container**

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { getThumbnails } from '../../../containers/search/sagas';
import createReducer from './reducers';

class ThumbnailsContainer extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.getThumbnails()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>My Container</div>
    )
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    getThumbnails: bindActionCreators(getThumbnails, dispatch)
  }
}


export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ThumbnailsContainer);
```

**Sagas.js**

```
export function* getThumbnails(dispatch) {

  console.log(dispatch)

  yield fetch('myAPIurl', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: {}
  }).then(res=>res.json())
    .then(res => {
      console.log(JSON.parse(res.data))
    });
}
```

**rootsagas.js**

```
import { all, fork } from 'redux-saga/effects';

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    fork(getThumbnails)
  ]);
}
```

**Stores.js**

```
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from 'redux';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import rootSaga from './rootsagas';

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const apolloMiddleware = apolloClient.middleware();

export default function configureStore(initialState = {}, history) {
  const middlewares = [
    sagaMiddleware
  ];
})

store.runSaga = sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
store.asyncReducers = {}; // Async reducer registry

const store = createStore(createReducer(), applyMiddleware(...middlewares));

store.runSaga = sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
store.asyncReducers = {}; // Async reducer registry

return store;
```

What i'd like to do is dispatch an action after I get my API response but can't seem to get a hold of the dispatch function. Can't see in their documentation where i've gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure whether correct or not. Try using `put` from `redux-saga`. Like below

```
import { put } from 'redux-saga/effects';

function* yourGenerator() {
  /*Your code*/
  yield put({ type: 'YOUR_ACTION', YOUR_PAYLOAD });
}
```

Read more about the dispatching action using saga [here](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/basics/DispatchingActions.html).

Comment: SO this is another way to do it but I can't get the generator function to fire from within the response function. If I have the yield put line within my final .then function after the API call then I get an error saying yield is a reserved word

Comment: Do not use generator functions as normal js promises. You can see this example https://github.com/ItsMrAkhil/mern/blob/master/app/containers/TasksPage/sagas.js